# Using Math methods to rewrite math function

Tags: java, math

I'm doing some exercises and i can't get around as to why I get errors. The exercises are on a student platform so I am not shown the compiler and cannot see all but the obvious compiler errors, it simply says: Expected: ok, Got: wrong expression.

The question is following

```
z = ae^x +be^-cos(x)
```

I wrote:

```
z = Math.pow( a * Math.E, x) + Math.pow(b * Math.E, -Math.cos(x));
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Your coefficients seem wrong. `a*Math.pow(Math.E, x)` for example would be the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if you want `(a * e) ^ x` it seems that it should be `a * (e ^ x)`:

```
 z = a * Math.pow(Math.E, x) + b * Math.pow(Math.E, -Math.cos(x));
```

Or since `Math.pow(Math.E, ...)` is just an exponent `Math.exp(...)`:

```
 z = a * Math.exp(x) + b * Math.exp(-Math.cos(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of precedence where exponentiation should be before multiplication.Before you multiply variable a with Math.E, you have operate expoentiation of Math.E and x.
The correct way is:

```
z = Math.pow(Math.E,x)*a + Math.pow(Math.E, -Math.cos(x))*b;
```